# Why is "cabal build" so slow compared with "make"?

Tags: haskell, build, cabal

If I have a package with several executables, which I initially build using `cabal build`. Now I change one file that impacts just one executable, cabal seems to take about a second or two to examine each executable to see if it's impacted or not. On the other hand, `make`, given an equivalent number of executables and source files, will determine in a fraction of a second what needs to be recompiled. Why the huge difference? Is there a reason, cabal can't just build its own version of a makefile and go from there?

Comment: Note that, while `make` will always recompile anything dependent on a touched file, `cabal build` will, for instance, not necessarily recompile downstream modules if you change only one function in a file. It somehow figures out that the interface isn't affected, and that it's enough to re-link the files (which is typically _much_ faster than recompiling anything). BTW, I think it's actually `ghc -make` that we should be talking about; cabal only invokes that for checking the dependencies within a package.

Answer (score 2):

Disclaimer: I'm not familiar enough with Haskell or `make` internals to give technical specifics, but some web searching does offer some insight that lines up with my proposal (trying to avoid eliciting opinions by providing references). Also, I'm assuming your makefile is calling `ghc`, as `cabal` apparently would.

Proposal: I believe there could be several key reasons, but the main one is that `make` is written in C, whereas `cabal` is written in Haskell. This would be coupled with superior dependency checking from `make` (although I'm not sure how to prove this without looking at the source code). Other supporting reasons, as found on the web:

- cabal tries to do a lot more than simply compiling, e.g. appears to take steps with regard to packaging (https://www.haskell.org/cabal/)
- cabal is written in haskell, although the run time is written in C (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glasgow_Haskell_Compiler)
- Again, not being overly familiar with `make` internals, `make` may simply have a faster dependency checking mechanism, thereby better tracking these changes. I point this out because from the OP it sounds like there is a significant enough difference to where cabal may be doing a blanket check against all dependencies. I suspect this would be the primary reason for the speed difference, if true.

At any rate, these are open source and can be downloaded from their respective sites (haskell.org/cabal/ and savannah.gnu.org/projects/make/) allowing anyone to examine specifics of the implementations.

It is also likely one could see a lot of variance in speed based upon the switches passed to the compilers in use.

HTH at least point you in the right direction.

Comment: Also, see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22630756/how-does-makefile-know-that-a-file-changed-and-then-recompile-it) SO thread; apparently make does a simple examination of time stamps to tell if something changed.

Comment: Cabal seems to look a [bit deeper](https://www.haskell.org/cabal/FAQ.html) for changes just due to the nature of its operation.

Comment: I don't know much about `cabal`s or `make`s internals either, but I'm fairly confident that the performance difference has little to do with the former being written in Haskell. Compiled Haskell is actually only a little slower than C, provided you keep away from certain performance traps (badly fused lists, too much lazyness etc.). In fact, sometimes an idiomatic Haskell implementation will be _faster_ than a not particularly optimised C solution!

Comment: You can *edit* your answer to incorporate new information or remove things that are found to be incorrect (such as the rather clearly false claim that Cabal is slower because it's written in Haskell rather than C).

Comment: @dfeuer: As @leftaroundabout points out, it's not always that simple to say whether one is faster or not (using words such as "little" and "sometimes" to indicate this). Especially bringing optimization into the mix (also begging the question: "would the distributed/release version of `make` *really* be un-optimized?"), one would need to *empirically* determine which is faster and *why*. Looking at the source code and the level of compiler optimization is certainly part of this.

Comment: My answer primarily provides some web research to try and help point people in the right direction. Looking at the source code, or performing some profiling experiments, would be two good ways for people to see for themselves.