# Determining if C++ code has changes since last make

Tags: python, c++

I am calling some C++ through a python code using the subprocess library. A number of times (in the past) I have made changes to the C++ code and forgotten to 'make' it and ran my python code. This resulted in it running the old version of the C++ code and making the results useless.

I have seen that some debuggers alert me that there were changes to the C++ code since the last 'make'. Is there a way to do this using python or some terminal command to alert me of this so that I avoid running old code.

Comment: Why not call `make` every time?

Comment: Somewhat related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22630756/how-does-makefile-know-that-a-file-changed-and-then-recompile-it

Comment: You can run `make -q` to check.

Comment: Typically this is detected by noting that one or more of the source files is newer than the executable. No rocket science here.

Comment: I tried make -q and that didnt do anything.

Comment: I was trying to ask this since I have forgotten to call make sometimes since I am calling my c-code through python. Wanted to have a warning/reminder if it did detect this issue