# AOSP "m" build command takes over hour after full build

Tags: android, android-source

I build Android framework project and build from AOSP 7.1.
AOSP full build takes 1 hour. It is fair time.
But after full build, I run "m" command on our project dir. It takes over hour.
"m" command shows like "1% 10/33239". It try to full build of 33239 file.

Someone know how to speed up AOSP "m" command?

Comment: After a full build did you do either of the following: touch source code files in any way that would affect their modified timestamps, or move anything in the `out` directory? Doing either of those things can trigger a lot of re-building. Source code files must have modified timestamps older than their output files or re-building will be performed. Also please provide the exact sequence of commands you executed for the full first build.

Comment: I do not touch or modify code or out directory. But somehow "m" command do full build. How "m" command find dependency?

Comment: m command works just like make, see this post for details https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22630756/how-does-makefile-know-that-a-file-changed-and-then-recompile-it

Answer (score 0):

`make` supports parallel jobs with a `-j` parameter. You can add all your cores here too. I run my builds with `-j$(nproc --all)` , and this way I am giving the maximum cpu to the build process. Also, keeping the out directory on an SSD wil be very useful. NVME SSDs are very fast for such workflow.

Full builds will always take more time since they will compile each and every other thing as well.

If hardware upgrades are not possible, best is to enable compiler cache (`ccache`) for the build process. I have these in place for AOSP purposes:

```
export USE_CCACHE=1
export CCACHE_EXEC=/usr/bin/ccache
export CCACHE_DIR=/path/to/fast/nvme/disk/folder
```

`ccache` also needs a size to be specified unless it stays at it's default 5GB size. Set that like: `ccache -M 50G`